# cakephp inset violating unique constraint

Tags: cakephp, insert, unique, constraints

using cakephp on email column in the db i have unique constraint, how can check before inserting recording that email may be duplicate or after inserting detect and print error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Core Validation Rules](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1152/Core-Validation-Rules). There's one for `isUnique`.

Answer (score 0):

Found another good example at http://www.davidtan.org/cakephp-tutorial-how-to-insert-records-into-table-with-unique-index-made-up-of-2-or-more-fields/

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.